# How do I install SQL Server Reporting Services for my version of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I believe the version of SQL Server 2012 that I have installed is a developer version.  It is version 11.0.3000.  I would like to install Reporting Services and Report Builder.  I tried this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/ff657833.aspx without any luck.  When I click the "Install Report Builder with Reporting Services" link I am brought to a page to download a trial of SQL Server 2012.  Is SQL Server Reporting already installed with my version of SQL Server ?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In the program manager group do you have a configure reporting services option; if you do follow the wizard to set it up. If you don't  put the disk in the server; and follow the installer; opting to install reporting service (remember to disable the server engine option.)

Answer (score 3):

To add Reporting Services to an existing SQL Server installation, instead of the typical install, navigate to the Control Panel->Programs and Features, locate Microsoft SQL Server 2012, and click Add

[image]

You will be prompted to select the SQL Server media location. (i.e. your DVD d
rive). Browse to the setup.exe file and click OK

[image]

SQL Server will gather information that it needs to modify components and check Install Setup files.  Click Ok or Next when prompted. When prompted to Select Instance, choose **Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2012** and click Next.

You will be prompted to verify Installation Rules, Disk Space Requirements, Error Reporting,
and Installation Configuration Rules, click Next.

Ready to Install will give you a summary, click Install

Answer (score 1):

Reload whatever medium you used to install SQL Server and install Reporting Services from there.  If reporting services is already installed then go to Start - All Programs - Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - Configuration Tools - Reporting Services Configuration Manager.  It'll prompt you to connect to an instance, it should default to the name of the server you're running the configuration on, click connect.

Go through and set everything up.